# transition object twice? (Corona SDK)

Tags: object, sdk, transition, coronasdk

i have a problem with transitioning!
For example:
i have an object and a button. I want this object to fade out when i press the button, and then when i press the button again i want my object to fade in.
But i can't fade in my object, feels like it's just gone!
For transition i use transition.to, for ex:

> object = transition.to( object, {time=500, alpha=0})

but when i perform another function in this exact scene to fade in, it just don't wanna work at all(button is pressing, but nothing is happening, even errors).

Help me out please!

Comment: post your code... specifically, post the code of how you transition back in

Answer (score 4):

Your code:

```
    object = transition.to( object, {time=500, alpha=0})
```

You are saving the transition handler to the object. Try this:

```
    trans = transition.to( object, {time=500, alpha=0})
```

Then if you want to cancel the transition you can do this

```
    transition.cancel(trans)
```

you can check the the usage of transition.to here http://developer.coronalabs.com/node/2407

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code i don't know correctly but it's works well:

```
local myRectangle = display.newRect(100, 100, 150, 50)
myRectangle.strokeWidth = 3
myRectangle:setFillColor(140, 140, 140)
myRectangle:setStrokeColor(180, 180, 180)

local button = display.newRect(100, 200, 50, 50)
button.strokeWidth = 3
button:setFillColor(140, 140, 140)
button:setStrokeColor(180, 180, 180)

local buttonfun=function(event)
if event.phase=="ended" then
print("fade")
if myRectangle.alpha ==1.0 then
transition.to( myRectangle, { delay=1, time=1000, alpha=1.0, alpha=0.0} )
myRectangle.alpha=0.0
print("alpha"..myRectangle.alpha)
else
transition.to( myRectangle, { delay=1, time=1000, alpha=0.0, alpha=1.0} )
myRectangle.alpha=1.0
print(myRectangle.alpha)
end
end
return true
end
button:addEventListener("touch", buttonfun)
```

Answer (score 0):

After  you  write this  `trans = transition.to( object, {time=500, alpha=0})`  in  button pressed first time so you  must chick  make boolen variable  to  make  this  action  twice. 
and  second  time  which  fade it  in  again  you  must make `alpha=1`

For example:

```
local  trans 
function  Listner  (event)
transition.cancel(trans)
trans = nil 
end

function  onPress(event)
if(flage== true) then 

flage = false  
trans = transition.to( object, {time=500, alpha=0 , onComplete =Listner  })

else
flage = true
trans = transition.to( object, {time=500, alpha=1 , onComplete =Listner  })

end
```